# Does the installation of same packages for two different python projects in two virtual environment result in wastage of memory?

Tags: python-3.x, django, memory, pip, python-venv

I was working on a `Django project` and got a doubt that if we have two projects running in our system say **P1 and P2** and both has its own **venv** as **V1 and V2**. At some point of time both project requires same python packages and I if am to install that package twice in my system result in wastage of space?
If so what is the use of virtual environment? Only to run projects in isolated environments?
Please can anyone tell me?

Comment: If `p1` and `p2` has ***"exact" same package requirements***, you don't need multiple venvs

Comment: Having the same package in multiple virtual environments would result in a "waste" of disk space not a waste of memory. Each process will load the package into memory wether it is shared or not

Comment: "*what is the use of virtual environment? Only to run projects in isolated environments?*" It's not "only", it's the very useful feature and the core of virtual environments. You can install **different versions** of packages in these isolated environments, including different versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

| category | Option A: P1 and P2 use **same** venv | Option B: P1 and P2 use **diff** venv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| disk size | required disk size is reused for packages | required disk size duplicates |
| mem size | still duplicates (same for A an B) | still duplicates (same for A an B) |
| benefit | less disk size required | isolation if P1 and P2 need diff package versions |